# Backbone - How to render singular model view from existing List View without fetching again & retaining history

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I tried to make the title more brief, and I might revise it once I can think of the proper way to pose the question, here it is:

I have a list view rendering multiple models representing data from a collection.

I want to be able to click one of the views/models, clear the view, and display ONLY that view (showing more info) - WITHOUT - fetching the data again, and retaining the history.

I've provided the single artifact view and the list view below:

```
// ArtifactView
App.ArtifactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className: '',
    template: Handlebars.compile($('#stream_getDigest').html()),
    render: function(){
        var id = this.options.artifact_id; // getting the ID from the route
        var artifactView = new App.ArtifactView({model: artifactSingleModel, id: id})
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.$el.find( ".link" ).attr( "href", "/artifact/" + this.model.id + "/" ); // adding link to the text
        return this;
    }
});

// ArtifactListView
App.ArtifactListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#here'),
    tagName: 'ul',
    id: 'list-view',
    initalize: function(){
        this.collection.on('add', this.addOne, this);
        this.collection.on('reset', this.addAll, this);
    },
    render: function(){
        this.addAll();
    },
    addOne: function(artifactModel){
        var artifactView = new App.ArtifactView({model: artifactModel});
        this.$el.append(artifactView.render().el);
    },
    addAll: function(){
        this.$el.empty(); // emptying the view
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    }
});
```

Comment: Presumably you have the collection in hand so you just need to know the model index or `id` so that you can pull the single model out of the collection. An HTML5 data-attribute would be one easy way. Hard to say more without knowing more about the collection-view's structure.

Comment: @muistooshort I've added the two view's to the OP

Comment: Couldn't you just add a click event handler to your `ArtifactView`? Then that handler could tell someone to clean up the page and render the model that the view already has. You could do similar things through a router if you could arrange for the router to have access to the model.

Comment: Is it possible to retain the current collection in a new route?

Comment: It might make sense to hold the collection as a property of your router or in a global `app` object so that everything can get at it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to have something happen when you click the view. For this, Backbone has the `events` object on it's `View`:

```
App.ArtifactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click': 'openDetailsView'
    },
    openDetailsView: function() {
        // Here you put the code to open the the code 
        // that should open the code that opens the
        // window that shows details about only this 
        // particular articaft.
    }
})
```

In the view you can access it's model with `this.model` (if it has a model) and then you can use that to get the attributes for that model to display it in the output.

Does that help you along?

Comment: Thanks, that's the easiest way to do this, but I don't think this will give me the routing capabilities i'm looking for. The end goal is to retain the data already loaded, but jump to a /artifact/:ID route.

Comment: If you don't want to have to fetch the data from the server again, just load in into your models the first time.